# What is the terminal on the photo?

Tags: pcb, identification, terminal, terminal-block

Does any one know what is the name of terminal on the photo? Or what is the kind of the shown connectors, not necessarily the exact one?

I tried sharpening the image and reading off the name but no results.

[image]

Comment: Google sullins connector solutions and enter the part number.

Comment: It’s an edge connector probably 0.156” pitch.

Comment: Do you mean the green card-edge connector?

Comment: Thank you very much, I found it.

Answer (score 1):

That is a card-edge connector, wide pitch (you can measure it). Quite popular in the 70-80. Well, the current PCIe and the memory slots in PCs are based on the same technology so it would be more correct to say that's still *a lot* in use.